# Calling javascript from page behind on page load event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, modal-dialog

I am trying to call the JavaScript "DisableAllPopUpTxt()" from the page behind with following code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:DisableAllPopUpTxt();", true);
```

But it is giving me following error:

**No overload of method RegisterStartupScript takes 4 aurguments**
Please tell me where I'm wrong.

Actually my **MasterPage** has one modal dialog registration form which has client side validations.
Because of validations I'm not able to do any post back.

So I'm trying to disable all text boxes using the JS function **"DisableAllPopUpTxt()"** on page load.

```
function DisableAllPopUpTxt() {

    document.getElementById("txtCustEmailID").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("txtCustPwd").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("txtCustFName").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("txtCustLName").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("txtCustREmail").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("txtCustRPwd").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("txtCustRePwd").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("txtCustPh").disabled = true;
}
```

But I'm not able to call it on page load.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: on load la he function ka call karat nahi?

Answer (score 3):

It takes 5 parametrs and you have passed 4 and in wrong way.

**It should be:**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:DisableAllPopUpTxt();", true);
```

**Syntax :**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method (Control, Type, String, String, Boolean);
```

Can follow example over [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/334535/passing-parameter-in-ScriptManager-RegisterStartup).

Answer (score 0):

Please try these changes also as you are using master page.

```
function DisableAllPopUpTxt() {

    document.getElementById("<%=txtCustEmailID.ClientID%>").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("<%=txtCustPwd.ClientID%>").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("<%=txtCustFName.ClientID%>").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("<%=txtCustLName.ClientID%>").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("<%=txtCustREmail.ClientID%>").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("<%=txtCustRPwd.ClientID%>").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("<%=txtCustRePwd.ClientID%>").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("<%=txtCustPh.ClientID%>").disabled = true;
}
```